# Inject guice managed dependency in a non guice class

Tags: java, hibernate, guice

I have a class (`CustomConnectionProvider`) which will be instantiated by a third party library (hibernate) using `class.forName().newInstance()`. I need to inject a guice managed dependency say `MyDatabaseFactory` which will provide data sources for multi-tenancy.

I can not directly `@Inject` the MyDatabaseFactory, because `CustomConnectionProvider` is not a managed bean. And I have no control over how it is being created.

I just started with Guice as part of a Play application. Any examples or ideas would be appreciated, I am looking for a solution like  `ServiceLocator`.

**Fixed for specific case**
Luckily, `Play.application()` provides a static method to get the `injector` and I'm using it to get the instance of my Factory. I still want to know if I have to fix it without play.

**Update for Play 2.5**
`Play.application()` is deprecated in 2.5. We need to use static injection as robert suggested.

Comment: Hey, is this hibernate specific? If so, there is: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GuicePersist which is the guice model for hibernate. If you need to do it manually, you should create the entitymanager (hibernate stuffs) in the Module where you create everything else. That way you'll get guice managed persistence. I do have an example for my case on the latter, however I am not using Play

Comment: @pandaadb, it is not specific to Hibernate. It is specific to injecting an object into another class which is not initialized by Guice at all and the initialization of that class is in some thirdparty library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static injection. See https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections

> It makes it possible for objects to partially participate in dependency injection, by gaining access to injected types without being injected themselves. Use

```
requestStaticInjection()
```

in a module to specify classes to be injected at injector-creation time:

```
@Override public void configure() { 
requestStaticInjection(ProcessorFactory.class); ... }
```

Guice will inject class's static members that have the @Inject annotation.

Comment: Link only answers should contain the relevant parts of the page included in your answer, can you please add some context?

Comment: It looks like this is the way to achieve, I will try and see if I can inject this way.

Comment: As the documentation mentioned, it is actually a not recommended way and it is really creating lot of problems. I had to change my way injection, I have posted it as another answer to this question. Which may help others with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `requestStaticInjection` is not a recommended way. As the [this link](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections) explains (`This API is not recommended for general use because it suffers many of the same problems as static factories: it's clumsy to test, it makes dependencies opaque, and it relies on global state.`), it creates many problems under few circumstances. The behaviour is not consistent and the injection is not successful all the times.

I had to take slightly different approach: My case is little complicated, the instance of my class will be created by Hibernate using `Class.forName()`, this may be yet another case where static injection *may* fail.

I had to create a Singleton factory which will be initialized and bind to Guice Injector at the start of the module creation, this factory will hold the actual bean which I need to inject into my actual class. It provides a static method to get the required bean.

```
public Class RequiredBeanFactory {
        private static RequiredBean bean;
        //note this is a package private
        RequiredBeanFactory(RequiredBean bean) {
            this.bean = bean;
        }

        public static RequiredBean getBean() {
            return bean;
        }
    }
```

In my Module, I am initializing it and binding.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final RequiredBean bean;

    @Inject
    public MyModule(RequiredBean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    protected void configure() {
        RequiredBeanFactory factory = new RequiredBeanFactory(this.bean);
        bind(RequireBeanFactory.class).toInstance(factory);
    }
}
```

In my HibernateCustom class, I just use `RequiredBeanFactory.getBean()`.

This is kind of a hack, may have the same side effects as Guice mentioned, but it is in my control and the behaviour is consistent.